# regular expression for Alpha numeric,no spaces and 9 character input?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I have used

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

for alphanumeric no spaces its working

now i have to limit only 9 character are allowed not more not less only 9

Comment: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" allows empty string while "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" requires at least one character.

Answer (score 12):

You can use curly braces to set limits on repetition:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}$"
```

That will only match strings in which the pattern in the character class is repeated exactly 9 times.

Note that you can also use this to limit repetition to a range. This example would only match strings in which the character class pattern is repeated between 3 and 5 times:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,5}$"
```

And you can leave out the second number but keep the comma to specify a *minimum* number of repetitions, so this one will match "at least 5":

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$"
```

Comment: +1. Not specifically needed for this question but you may want to consider mentioning the form `{min,max}` as well as what you have, `{exact}`.

Comment: @paxdiablo - Thanks, was editing that in as you wrote your comment!

Comment: Yeah, thought the update was a bit fast :-) Unfortunately, can't upvote again but hopefully you'll get some more. But as long as you're adding `{5,}` does JS also allow `{,5}`? Never mind, appears not (this seems a bit of a hole in the syntax to me). Although I guess you _always_ know the lower bound in that case (0) whereas the upper bound is arbitrarily high.

Comment: Quick answer. I'll give some more :) Also you could add nice online regex generator:  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/  Helps a lot in such work.

Comment: @paxdiablo - Exactly, you will always know the lower bound so that syntax is unnecessary.

Comment: you are absolutely right but i am parsing the validator from a xslt for that reason its ommiting braces{}. so expression getting as ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]9$" .can i use a range validator to solve the same .here i am creating dynamic controls from xslt

Comment: @RahulChowdhury - Sorry, I'm not sure. Can you escape the braces to keep them in the string?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use Range Validator with your regular expression validator. or go with 
James Allardice solution, it may also help you. but I will suggest to use Range Validator as well with your Regular Expression [click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk58fdzx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)